# Seems there is no newline only full width div in \code block made by DOXYGEN

Tags: doxygen

I haven't had updated my doxygen for some years and after updating I saw something strange and despite of my tries I couldn't correct it.
The problem is when I create a code block in my documentation file like:

```
\code{.py}
from GPIUTMD_script import *

# create 1000 random particles of name A
init.create_random(N=1000, phi_p=0.01, name='A')

# specify Lennard-Jones interactions between particle pairs
lj = pair.lj(r_cut=3.0)
lj.pair_coeff.set('A', 'A', epsilon=1.0, sigma=1.0)

# integrate at constant temperature
all = group.all()
integrate.mode_standard(dt=0.005)
integrate.nvt(group=all, T=1.2, tau=0.5)

# dump a .mol2 file for the structure information
mol2 = dump.mol2()
mol2.write(filename='example1.mol2')

# dump a .dcd file for the trajectory
dump.dcd(filename='example1.dcd', period=100)

# run 10,000 time steps
run(10e3)
\endcode
```

I get what I should in the chm file but when I try to copy the code into a text editor it has no newlines in it. when I checked the source of the generated chm I saw it has each line put in a div block with full width but no line break:

```
<div class="fragment">
<div class="line"><a name="l00001"></a><span class="lineno">    1</span>&#160;from GPIUTMD_script <span class="keyword">import</span> *</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00002"></a><span class="lineno">    2</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00003"></a><span class="lineno">    3</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># create 1000 random particles of name A</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00004"></a><span class="lineno">    4</span>&#160;init.create_random(N=1000, phi_p=0.01, name=<span class="stringliteral">&#39;A&#39;</span>)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00005"></a><span class="lineno">    5</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00006"></a><span class="lineno">    6</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># specify Lennard-Jones interactions between particle pairs</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00007"></a><span class="lineno">    7</span>&#160;lj = pair.lj(r_cut=3.0)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00008"></a><span class="lineno">    8</span>&#160;lj.pair_coeff.set(<span class="stringliteral">&#39;A&#39;</span>, <span class="stringliteral">&#39;A&#39;</span>, epsilon=1.0, sigma=1.0)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00009"></a><span class="lineno">    9</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00010"></a><span class="lineno">   10</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># integrate at constant temperature</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00011"></a><span class="lineno">   11</span>&#160;all = group.all()</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00012"></a><span class="lineno">   12</span>&#160;integrate.mode_standard(dt=0.005)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00013"></a><span class="lineno">   13</span>&#160;integrate.nvt(group=all, T=1.2, tau=0.5)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00014"></a><span class="lineno">   14</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00015"></a><span class="lineno">   15</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># dump a .mol2 file for the structure information</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00016"></a><span class="lineno">   16</span>&#160;mol2 = dump.mol2()</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00017"></a><span class="lineno">   17</span>&#160;mol2.write(filename=<span class="stringliteral">&#39;example1.mol2&#39;</span>)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00018"></a><span class="lineno">   18</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00019"></a><span class="lineno">   19</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># dump a .dcd file for the trajectory</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00020"></a><span class="lineno">   20</span>&#160;dump.dcd(filename=<span class="stringliteral">&#39;example1.dcd&#39;</span>, period=100)</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00021"></a><span class="lineno">   21</span>&#160;</div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00022"></a><span class="lineno">   22</span>&#160;<span class="comment"># run 10,000 time steps</span></div>
<div class="line"><a name="l00023"></a><span class="lineno">   23</span>&#160;run(10e3)</div>
</div>
```

One of the reasons I am using \code command is to give my documentation users the chance to copy and paste the example scripts and syntax from the user manual for easier use.
I would be glad if someone could help me correcting this (I want to have the <\br> tag or something that help copying this text to a simple text editor with newlines included).

Regards